# How works Embers `toString` and how to give my Ember Objects fancy names?

Tags: ember.js

I write some Ember code (an `ember-cli` addon) where I have custom helper Objects.

There I have some Computed Properties that return helper object instances.

For example a simple Mixin:

```
// my-addon/cool-mixin
import Ember from 'ember';
import CoolThing from 'my-addon/cool-thing';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    coolThing: Ember.computed('foo', {
        return CoolThing.create({
            foo : this.get('foo')
        });
    })
});

// my-addon/cool-thing
import Ember form 'ember';
export default Ember.Object.create({});
```

Now everything works fine but when I use this Mixin I always get instances of `(subclass of Ember.Object)`, which is not nice:

```
import Ember form 'ember';
import CoolMixin from 'my-addon/cool-mixin';
Ember.Controller.extend(CoolMixin, {
    actions: {
        debug() {
            alert(this.get('coolThing').toString()); // here I cant something like "myAddon.CoolThing" or anything usefull
        }
    }
});
```

What is the best way to give my Object a fancy name?
It works nice for Ember internal Objects (like `ObjectProxy`), but I cant find the code how they do it!

I know that if I lookup the Object with the container everything gets a fancy name, but how to get it for static imports?

So:

1. How does `Ember.ObjectProxy` get its cool name?
2. What is the best way for me to give Objects a name in my addon?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can implement `toString` for your classes and it'll be called when outputting. See [Ember.Object](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.4.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/object.js#L21-L23) for reference.

Comment: Sure I could do this. But Ember itself somehow gives the name automatically. How and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value for the key `Ember.NAME_KEY`. This will be used instead of `(subclass of X)`, unless you override `toString`.

See this similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588126/1911487